# Fields inserting blank data into database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've checked my code compared with code elsewhere on my site and I can't see any inconsistencies, but for some reason the records are entering my database with blank data, here is my code.

```
<?php

include '../includes/connect.php';
include '../header.php';

echo '<h2>Create a Sub category</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false | $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
{
//the user is not an admin
echo 'Sorry, you do not have sufficient rights to access this page.';
}
else
{
//the user has admin rights
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    //the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Category name: ';
        $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<select name="topic_cat">';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo '</select><br />';


    echo 'Sub category name: <input type="text" name="sub_cat_name" /><br />
        Sub category description:<br /> <textarea name="sub_desc" /></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Sub Category" />
     </form>';
}
else
{

    //the form has been posted, so save it
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
       VALUES('" . $_POST['categories.cat_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_cat_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_desc'] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            echo 'The sub category <b>' . $row['sub_cat_name'] . '</b> has been added under the main category <b>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</b>';
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Error' . mysql_error();

    }
}
}
; ?>
```

My **categories** table is structured like so..

- cat_id
- cat_desc

My **subcategories** table is structured like so..

- id(AI)
- c_id
- sub_cat_name
- sub_desc

If I haven't provided enough information please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. **[Please, don't use the mysql_* functions for new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)** They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the **[red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)**? You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead - [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which to use.

Comment: I don't see where the variables in your insert statement ($cat_id, $sub_cat_name, $sub_desc) are being set from the POST data.

Comment: Not only is your code using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, but you're extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks by just including the variables directly into your query without any sort of escaping.

Comment: Please tell me the other pages on your site aren't depending on the `register_globals` config to automatically put any POST values into variables.

Comment: instead of `"INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc) VALUES('" . $cat_id . "', '" . $sub_cat_name . "', '" . $sub_desc . "')";` you can use `"INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc) VALUES('$cat_id', '$sub_cat_name', '$sub_desc')";` . This makes code more readable.

Comment: thanks for your concern JCSANYI but the page I am working on is admin only, meaning only I can input from this page, so I'm not worried about me hacking myself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be reading the $POST variables into the variables you're using in your query. You probably want something like this:

```
$sub_cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sub_cat_name']);
// repeat for other variables.
```

Comment: @jcsanyi I knew you'd comment if I didn't!

Comment: Thank you, that added all the fields accept for the c_id which is from cat_id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `$cat_id` `$sub_cat_name` and `$sub_desc` are not defined anywhere.

Also, you're missing a pipe here:

```
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false || $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
// --------------------------------^
```

Lastly, I should note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should really be using mysqli or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false || $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
------------------------------------^ (OR)
```

**I also don't see where you set the variables.** `('" . $cat_id . "' and etc...)`

You should store them into a `variable` like so:

```
$cat_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name_of_the_input']); //and etc..
```

**Or in your `insert query` do this:** (Depending on the values whether or not you need to escape it like above)

```
'".$_POST['name_of_input']."',
```

Comment: I tried the .$_POST. suggestion, it's entering all the fields except for the category ID from the category table into the sub-category table.

$sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
     VALUES('" . $_POST['cat_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_cat_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_desc'] . "')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: Change this `echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">';' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';` to this: echo "`<option value="$row['cat_id']">$row['cat_name']</option>";` If that doesn't fix it try storing the id in a variable and then do this. '$catId = $row['cat_id']; $catName = $row['cat_name']; <option value="$catId">$catName</option>";` I think your main problem is that cat id is not in the value in your form.

Comment: Not working for me :( somehow I am not selecting the information from the categories table to insert into the sub categories table it seems, I can add to the sub categories table, but it doesn't relay the cat_id  into the c_id in sub categories table.

Comment: When you look at the html the cat_id is not in the value?

Comment: I just editing my open post to update the code changes, that is the entire file, it's putting all of the sub_category fields in except for the c_id being inserted from the cat_id from the categories table.